# Remove all tags except wanted tags with JS regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

i need to remove all tags except a list of allowed tags from a string. I must use regex in javascript.

So if i have in my string :

```
<html>
    <b>my text</b> is just <strong>an example</strong>
</html>
```

and my list of allowed tags is : b, strong

the result must be :

```
<b>my text</b> is just <strong>an example</strong>
```

Seems to be simple, but regex are getting me out of me :)

Thanks a lot dear friends !

Comment: So you want to parse HTML with Regex?

Comment: No, OP wants to strip it, which is easier.

Comment: Phew, I though I could hear the sound of hooves... Pony hooves.  Lucky I was wrong  :)

Comment: Correctly stripping HTML involves parsing it, which cannot be done with regex alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just looked this up on phpjs.org:  http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535

```
function strip_tags (input, allowed) {
    allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
    var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
        commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
    return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
        return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });
}
```

NOT my code, but it will do as you ask - strip tags with exceptions you specify.

Comment: Thanks, Surreal Dreams that's it ! I wasn't looking on php websites :)

Comment: Do we really need the commentsAndPhpTags?